# tensorflow change/assign matrix element values by list of (different range of 2d) slices

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, slice

I have a zero matrix (we can view it as a picture):

`matrix = tf.zeros(name="matrix", shape=(4, 5), dtype=tf.int32)`

and tensor of tetrads that indicate some "boxes" (by top-left and bottom-right vertex, maybe overlapped) on this `matrix`:

`(first_row, first_column, second_row, second_column)`

here, `[first_row:second_row, first_column,second_column]` forms one box on the `matrix`.

And the question is: how can i assign/change all the "boxed value" on the picture from `0` to `1`, using the slicing `[first_row:second_row, first_column,second_column]` or other tensorflow functions?

**Update**:

Input:

`matrix = tf.zeros(name="matrix", shape=(4, 5), dtype=tf.int32)`

```
first_row = tf.constant([0,2])
first_column = tf.constant([2,1])
second_row = tf.constant([3,3])
second_column = tf.constant([3,3])
```

The expected output (by boxes example `(0,2,3,3)` and `(2,1,3,3)`):

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Can you give the input and output examples ? You could update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help. But if it doesn't you could clarify your question.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.Variable(
    [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])


with tf.Session() as sess :
  sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
  print(sess.run( tf.assign(tensor[0:1,2:3] , [[9]] )))
```

Output is this.

```
[[0 0 9 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]]
```

And if you change the last line to `print(sess.run( tf.assign(tensor[0:1,2:4] , [[9,9]] )))` you get

```
[[0 0 9 9 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]]
```

When I don't ensure the left-side of the assignment doesn't match the right side in terms of shape I get this error. This should help you.

> sliced l-value shape [1,2] does not match r-value shape [1,1]

And the example `print(sess.run( tf.assign(tensor[0:2,2:4] , [[9,9],[9,9]] )))` prints

```
[[0 0 9 9 0]
 [0 0 9 9 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solve the left and right value consistency by specify their dimensions.